# How to run grpc on ipv4 only

Tags: python, grpc

I'm going to run a grpc server on IPv4 address like this:

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
protoc_pb2_grpc.add_ProtocServicer_to_server(StockProtocServicer(), server)
server.add_insecure_port('0.0.0.0:5000')
server.start()
```

But it it's listening to IPv6. Here is the output for `lsof -i -n -P | grep 5000`:

```
python    7302             dev    6u  IPv6 224100      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

I've tested listening on IPv6 to see what happens, like this:

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
protoc_pb2_grpc.add_ProtocServicer_to_server(UserProtocServicer(), server)
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:5000')
server.start()
```

but the result was the same:

```
python    7366             dev    6u  IPv6 225782      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

I also tried to use the actual IP address instead of `0.0.0.0`:

```
python    7392             dev    6u  IPv6 226111      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.23:5000 (LISTEN)
```

Although I can use the server's IPv4 address on my client, I want to run the server only on IPv4. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** If you use an IPv4 address, it's using IPv4, not IPv6. You have what you want, even though `lsof` says `IPv6`.

---

### `lsof` and `"IPv4-mapped IPv6 address"` explanation

When using the IPv4 address, my python client still shows `type` as IPv6 when `lsof -nP -i4TCP | grep appname`.

From `man lsof`:

> When an open IPv4 network file's address is **mapped in an IPv6 address**,
> the open file's type will be IPv6, not IPv4, and its display will be
> selected by '6', not '4'.

This means our applications uses the IPv6 network file/socket, but it uses the IPv4 protocol. Apparently, this is convenient for applications (e.g. python, gRPC) to handle - they don't have to worry about IPv4 and IPv6, they just support IPv6 and it will map to IPv4 if needed.

For more information about mapped addresses, see

- [Purpose of IPv4 mapped IPv6 address](https://serverfault.com/a/1102261).
- [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=addresses-ipv4-mapped-ipv6)

---

### Bonus question:

What if you only have the **domain** name (e.g. google.com) and want to use IPv4, not IPv6, even though the IPv6 DNS record (`AAAA`) exists: `dig AAAA google.com`).

**Answer:** To do this, you could use `dig A example.com` and use that the server address. *I am looking for a better way to do this though.*