# Run python http.server for IPv6 only

Tags: python

`python3 -m http.server --bind ::` launches a python web server, as shown in [Python 3: Does http.server support ipv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55501674/7365866). However, it also supports IPv4, because I can visit the web server with `localhost:8000` (edit: even `127.0.0.1:8000` works). I don't want that. The python `http.server` is dual-stack even though I used `--bind`:

> By default, server binds itself to all interfaces. The option -b/--bind specifies a specific address to which it should bind. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html)

**Is there a way to disable IPv4?** I asked it to bind to `::`.

Comment: The "localhost" name is an alias in both IPv4 and IPv6.  "localhost" maps to "::".  Does it work if you do `127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: Yea, my browser can visit `127.0.0.1:8000`. Though, I didn't know localhost resolves to `::`. It's true: `dig AAAA localhost` gets `::1`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There is no way to do this because the support for IPv4 is not provided by Python, but by the OS.* **I'm not 100% sure though.**

### More details

The output of `lsof -nP -i4TCP | grep LISTEN` (open network files/sockets on IPv4) include (notice the `IPv6`)

```
Python    30838  ben    3u  IPv6 0xb364e79e7fc44213      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
```

This is alongside the IPv6 network file `lsof -nP -6` (warning: `lsof -nP -i6TCP` doesn't show it ):

```
Python    30838  ben    3u  IPv6 0xb364e79e7fc44213      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
```

I think the OS creates a network file/socket for IPv4 packets even though Python did not ask for it (for convenience). From my understanding of `lsof` and the docs:

> When an open IPv4 network file's address is **mapped in an IPv6 address**,
> the open file's type will be IPv6, not IPv4, and its display will be
> selected by '6', not '4'.

I've just realized this is a very similar "feature" to one I was reading [yesterday...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559461/how-to-run-grpc-on-ipv4-only/74197641#74197641)

This means it's no longer a Stack Overflow answer but a Linux one: How do you turn off dual-stack networking for the server?